# How to get last 3 distinct prices based on a date column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table which contains these columns;

- CODE
- PRICE
- DATE

  So what i want to do is to get last 3 **distinct** price values per id ordered by date column. Basically the most recent 3 distinct prices per id.

Also there is an ID column in the table. It is the primary key of the table.

Edit: As ughai said, DISTINCT doesn't work with row_number.  [image: Here is the result set when i execute the cte block.]

Comment: Specify sample data and expected result

Comment: I take it ID is not the Primary key?

Comment: You appear to allow duplicate date values. What result should be obtained if there are more than 3 distinct price values across less than 3 distinct date values?

Comment: Date values can be duplicate, it's not important. I just want to get the most recent 3 different prices .Even if there all date values are the same, i still want to get 3 different prices.

Comment: Yes, but my question is, **which** three prices do we choose if there are, say, 4 (or more) different prices for the most recent date? Or do we choose more than 3 prices in that circumstance?

Comment: For example; if there are 4 different prices for the most recent date, then i would like to see first 3 prices ordered by another unique column of the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select t.id , c.Price 
from TableName t 
   CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT TOP 3 Price
                FROM TableName s
                WHERE s.ID = t.ID
                ORDER BY [DATE] DESC
                ) c (Price)
GROUP BY t.id ,  c.Price
```